# jQuery submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

## html code

```
<div id="signup">
    <form  id="suform" method="POST" action="roma/roma">
        <p>
            <label>Frist Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="sufName"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="sulName"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="suEmail"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Mobile Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="suMNumber"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="suPassword"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Re Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="suRePassword"/>
            <span class="errorMessage"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="sign up"/>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

**it is just six input fields to make a sign up page**
and this is the jQuery code to ensure that there is no input field empty, and if there is no input field empty I want to submit the form.

## jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#suform').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var errorCount = 0;
        $('span.errorMessage').text(''); // reset all error mesaage
        $('input').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() === ''){
                var error = 'Please fill ' + $this.prev('label').text(); // take the input field from label
                $this.next('span').text(error);
                errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
            }
        });
        if(errorCount === 0){
            $(this).submit(); // submit form if no error
        }
    });
});
```

The code ensure that there is no input field empty, it found an empty one then an error message will appear, else should submit, but the submit doesn't work.

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/h9njC/22/)

Comment: I don't know the exact problem. but you know there's this function in jquery? http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: and i am using it, see it the last line in jquery code  , the question is why this submit doesn't work ?

Comment: You should really consider using a [jQuery plugin for validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) instead of this.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan ah I didn't spot it ^^;

Comment: try this: if(errorCount !== 0){
            return false;
          }    and test your form with other browsers too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `$(this)[0].submit();`. Using $(this) refers to the jQuery object reference to the form. I don't know what jQuery's `submit()` method actually does, but it clearly *doesn't* submit the form. Using `$(this)[0]` refers to the actual DOM element, which will use the standard DOM submit method, which is what you're looking for.

I'm sure you know this already, but you should use server *and* client side validation, because some users don't have JS and some users will purposely tamper with your form. Just a quick "Don't forget"!

Comment: you the one man , it works thank you i will accept the answer when i allow to do that

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). For this you add a `class = "required"` for any input field that is required, and just call `validation` on it:

```
$('form').validation({
  // any options you want
});
```

It will also do handy things like displaying error messages, doing conditional validation, etc.

Comment: Yep exactly. You'll need to include the actual plugin, and the documentation is all available on the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `e.preventDefault()` and use `return` insead:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    var errorCount = 0;
    $('span.errorMessage').text('');
    $('input').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.val() === ''){
            var error = 'Please fill ' + $this.prev('label').text();
            $this.next('span').text(error);
            errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
        }
    });
    return errorCount === 0;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/h9njC/27/

Comment: thank you , but i need to make e.preventDefault , the answer was $(this)[0].submit()

Comment: Just out of interest, why you need `e.preventDefault` here?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
    var errorCount = 0;
    $('span.errorMessage').text('');
    $('input').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.val() === ''){
            var error = 'Please fill ' + $this.prev('label').text();
            $this.next('span').text(error);
            errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
        }
    });
    if(errorCount === 0){
        alert('done'); // just an alert to notice when everything OK [remove it]
        $this.submit(); // submit the form on success
    } else e.preventDefault(); // halt the submission on default
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h9njC/30/)**

Comment: @William Kinaan I think you want something like this. check the code and the demo